# I can't download anything from repositories

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I want to download a packet from one of the Ubuntu repositories and when I enter `apt-get install "thepacket"` I get the following error: `megajc-reloaded needs to be reinstalled, but no files can be found for it`. I also tried to use Ubuntu software center and it tells me that the package catalog needs to be repaired. So I click on `repair` but it fails to repair it. Then I entered `sudo dpkg --configure -a` but it didn't fix the issue either. What can I do? 
Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I managed to solve the problem thanks to Ubuntu Software Center as I said before but this time it fixed it.

Comment: try removing the offending package and running "apt-get -f install" afterwards

Comment: i.e. ``sudo apt-get remove megajc-reloaded && sudo apt-get -f install``

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the **Repair** button in Ubuntu Software Center, the system may be able to repair this automatically.